# How to reduce this size?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, apk

[image]

bundle size is too big how to reduce this any help please.

Comment: These files are native libraries. usually they are included because you use a Java library which included one ore more of them. So check the list of your used libraries. If you upload an app bundle to Google your app users will only get one of the lib sub-folder (the one that matches the used device platform).

Answer (score 1):

try to set the minifyEnabled true at the application build.gradle, it may help a little

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use SVG Images instead of PNG etc.
and if you need png so compare your image.
Comprece Image Refcese :[link](https://tinypng.com/)

use less Library.
Clean Code that you don't need like log etc.

Comment: Please don't post text as screen-shot.